# Salesforce quote rate rating

Tags: salesforce, rating, quote, vlocity

We are trying to use the Rate Now service to get price for a quote line item. The rate now is calling priceRootItem method on InsurancePCRuntimeHandler class.

If we set an Expression Set as Rating Procedure Type on the product, we get the price correctly (hardcoded) but when we try to use an Integration Procedure we get the error 'There is no rating result returned. Please check your rating procedure.'

Even though we hardcoded the the IP response to be just like the one from the expression set.

Does anyone know the correct json format/structure we need to return from the integration procedure so the priceRootItem method can read it correctly?

Here is the documentation we based on but without using rating facts: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=ind.v_health_t_use_rating_fact_to_rate_a_health_plan_472499.htm&type=5

Here is the priceRootItem mehtod but from an old apex class (I imagine)

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=ind.v_health_insquoteservice__pricerootitem.htm&type=5

We try these response formats along others

```
"output": {
        "aggregationResults": {
            "FinalTotalPrice": 1821.12
        },
        "calculationResults": [
            {
                "NumberAdjustForGroupSize": 1.075,
                "Plan_Code_Base_Price__ProductCodeOut": "P42PPO",
                "Plan_Code_Base_Price__BasePrice": 255.29,
                "FinalGroupSizePercentage": 0.075,
                "CalculatedPlanPriceTierFAM": 2731.68,
                "TotalPremium": 1821.12,
                "FinalRatePMPM": 455.28,
                "CalculatedPlanPriceTierEC": 1639.01,
                "CalculatedPlanPriceTierES": 2003.23,
                "CalculatedPlanPriceTierEE": 910.56
            }
        ]
    }
```

---

```
{
    "ouput": [
      {
        "calculationResults": [
          {
            "parentProdKey": "0QL74000000LhgcGAC",
            "productKey": "0QL74000000LhgcGAC",
            "ID": "userInputs",
            "totalPremium": 1805.04,
            "CalculatedPlanPriceTierFAM": 2707.56,
            "CalculatedPlanPriceTierES": 1985.54,
            "CalculatedPlanPriceTierEC": 1624.54,
            "CalculatedPlanPriceTierEE": 902.52,
            "FinalRatePMPM": 451.26,
            "NumberAdjustForGroupSize": 1.075,
            "FinalGroupSizePercentage": 0.075,
            "Plan_Code_Base_Price__BasePrice": 255.29,
            "Plan_Code_Base_Price__ProductCodeOut": "P42PPO"
          }
        ],
        "aggregationResults": {
          "totalPremium": 1805.04
        }
      }
    ],
    "input": [
      {
        "FinalTotalCoveredLivesFactor": "1.1100",
        "TotalNumEmpWithSpouses": "0.00",
        "ProductCode": "P42PPO",
        "Size": "2.00",
        "TotalNumEmpChildOnly": "0.00",
        "TotalNumEmpFamily": "0.00",
        "AreaFactor": "1.0000",
        "QuoteLoadFactor": "1.00",
        "TotalNumEmpOnly": "2.00",
        "AverageLivesPerEmployee": "2.0000",
        "TierTemp": "EE",
        "EffectiveDate": "2023-10-01"
      }
    ]
  }
```

we were expecting to update the quote line item price

Thanks in advance!

Regards!!

Comment: You should ensure that the key names in your JSON response exactly match those expected by Salesforce. Even minor deviations in key names or data types can cause issues.

Comment: You may have more luck on dedicated sister site salesforce.stackexchange.com. there's not much coding in your question, config (even if complex json) will have more admins and health cloud consultants over there